# What is the difference between those tensors

Tags: notation, tensors, scientific-notation

Recently I was studying quantum electrodynamics and got a small question about tensors.

The Lagrangian of QED has this thing
$\frac{1}{4}F^{\mu \nu}F_{\mu \nu}$

And I can't understand the difference between $F_{\mu \nu}$ and $F^{\mu \nu}$

Also there is unusual derivative with such notation
$\partial ^{\mu}$ and usual $\partial _{\mu}$

So my question is what does this notation mean?

Thank you!

Comment: It's called "raising an index". Given a covector $\omega$, the values $\omega^i$ are the components of $\omega^\sharp$, its "sharp". These are called the "musical isomorphisms". Read about them [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musical_isomorphism) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raising_and_lowering_indices).

Comment: Have you taken a course in differential geometry?

Comment: Hello! Not yet. I'm studying some stuff myself just for fun. So I guess I need to see what is this all about. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It would be digestible if we can translate everything from tensor calculus to vector calculus, please see most typical results below:**

- Regard zero rank tensors as numbers, first rank as vectors, second rank as matrices , etc.
- Lazy notations

$$\mathbf{a}=\sum_i a_i \mathbf{e}_i=a_i \mathbf{e}_i$$

$$\mathbb{AB}=\sum_j a_{ij} b_{jk}=a_{ij} b_{jk}=c_{ik}$$

- Zero vector and identity matrix

$$\mathbf{0}=0\, \mathbf{e}_{i}$$

$$\mathbb{I}=\delta_{ij}$$

- Dot product

$$\mathbf{a}^T \mathbf{b}=
\begin{pmatrix}
  a_1 & a_2 & a_3
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
  b_1 \\ b_2 \\ b_3
\end{pmatrix}=
\mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{b}=
\delta_{ij} a_i b_j=a_i b_i$$

- Matrix multiplication

$$\mathbb{A} \mathbb{B}=
\begin{pmatrix}
  a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\
  a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\
  a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
  b_{11} & b_{12} & b_{13} \\
  b_{21} & b_{22} & b_{23} \\
  b_{31} & b_{32} & b_{33}
\end{pmatrix}
=a_{ij} b_{jk}$$

- Levi-Civita tensor

$$\epsilon_{ijk}=\frac{(i-j)(j-k)(k-i)}{2} \quad \quad i,j,k\in \{ 1,2,3 \}$$

$$\det \mathbb{A}=
\begin{vmatrix}
  a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\
  a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\
  a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33}
\end{vmatrix}=\frac{\epsilon_{ijk} \epsilon_{pqr} a_{ip} a_{jq} a_{kr}}{3!}$$

- Cross product

$$\mathbf{a} \times \mathbf{b}=
\begin{pmatrix}
  0 & -a_3 & a_2 \\
  a_3 & 0 & -a_1 \\
  -a_2 & a_1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
  b_1 \\ b_2 \\ b_3
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
  0 & b_3 & -b_2 \\
  -b_3 & 0 & b_1 \\
  b_2 & -b_1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
  a_1 \\ a_2 \\ a_3
\end{pmatrix}=
\epsilon_{ijk} a_i b_j \mathbf{e}_k$$

$$\mathbf{a}^T \times \mathbf{b}^T=
\begin{pmatrix}
  a_1 & a_2 & a_3
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
  0 & -b_3 & b_2 \\
  b_3 & 0 & -b_1 \\
  -b_2 & b_1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
  b_1 & b_2 & b_3
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
  0 & a_3 & -a_2 \\
  -a_3 & 0 & a_1 \\
  a_2 & -a_1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$

- Metric for flat space-time

$$g^{\mu \nu}=g_{\mu \nu}=
\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & \mathbf{0}^T \\
  \mathbf{0} & -\mathbb{I} \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

- Covariant and contravariant vectors

$$x_\mu=
\begin{pmatrix}
  ct \\ -\mathbf{r}
\end{pmatrix}=
g_{\mu \nu} x^{\nu}$$

$$x^\mu=
\begin{pmatrix}
  ct \\ \mathbf{r}
\end{pmatrix}=
g^{\mu \nu} x_{\nu}$$

- Four gradients

$$\partial^\mu = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_\mu}=
\begin{pmatrix}
  \dfrac{1}{c} \partial_t \\ -\nabla
\end{pmatrix}$$

$$\partial_\mu = \frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu}=
\begin{pmatrix}
  \dfrac{1}{c} \partial_t \\ \nabla
\end{pmatrix}$$

$$\partial^\mu = g^{\mu \nu} \partial_\nu$$

$$\partial_\mu = g_{\mu \nu} \partial^\nu$$

$$\square^2=
\partial^\mu \partial_\mu=
\partial_\mu \partial^\mu=
\nabla^2-\frac{1}{c^2} \frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}$$

- Time dilation factor and proper time

$$\gamma_u=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\dfrac{u^2}{c^2}}}$$

$$d\tau=\frac{dt}{\gamma_u}$$

$$\frac{d\gamma_u}{d\tau}=\frac{\gamma_u^4}{c^2} (\mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{u})$$

- Four-vectors for velocity, acceleration and jerk

$$u^\mu= \frac{dx^\mu}{d\tau}=\gamma_u
\begin{pmatrix}
  c \\ \mathbf{u}
\end{pmatrix}$$

$$a^\mu= \frac{du^\mu}{d\tau}$$

$$b^\mu= \frac{da^\mu}{d\tau}$$

- Miscellaneous four-vectors

$$p^\mu=m_0 u^\mu=
\begin{pmatrix}
  \dfrac{E}{c} \\ \mathbf{p}
\end{pmatrix}=
\gamma_u m_0
\begin{pmatrix}
  c \\ \mathbf{u}
\end{pmatrix}$$

$$F^\mu=\gamma_u
\begin{pmatrix}
  \dfrac{\mathbf{F} \cdot \mathbf{u}}{c} \\ \mathbf{F}
\end{pmatrix}$$

$$k^\mu=
\begin{pmatrix}
  \dfrac{\omega}{c} \\ \mathbf{k}
\end{pmatrix}$$

$$J^\mu=
\begin{pmatrix}
  \rho c \\ \mathbf{J}
\end{pmatrix}$$

$$A^\mu=
\begin{pmatrix}
  \dfrac{\phi}{c} \\ \mathbf{A}
\end{pmatrix}$$

$$K^\mu=
\begin{pmatrix}
  \dfrac{\mathbf{E} \cdot \mathbf{J}}{c} \\
  \rho \mathbf{E}+\mathbf{J} \times \mathbf{B}
\end{pmatrix}$$

- Lorentz matrix

$${\Lambda^\mu}_\nu=
\begin{pmatrix}
   \gamma_v & -\dfrac{\gamma_v}{c} \mathbf{v}^T \\
  -\dfrac{\gamma_v}{c} \mathbf{v} & \mathbb{I}+
   \left(
     \dfrac{\gamma_v-1}{v^2} \mathbf{v}
   \right) \mathbf{v}^T ​\\
\end{pmatrix}=
{\Lambda_\nu}^\mu$$

$${\Lambda_\mu}^\nu=
\begin{pmatrix}
  \gamma_v & \dfrac{\gamma_v}{c} \mathbf{v}^T \\
  \dfrac{\gamma_v}{c} \mathbf{v} & \mathbb{I}+
  \left(
    \dfrac{\gamma_v-1}{v^2} \mathbf{v}
  \right) \mathbf{v}^T ​\\
\end{pmatrix}=
{\Lambda^\nu}_\mu$$

$${\Lambda^\nu}_\mu=({\Lambda_\mu}^\nu)^{-1}$$

- Field tensors

$$F^{\mu \nu}=\partial^\mu A^\nu-\partial^\nu A^\mu=
\begin{pmatrix}
  0 & -\dfrac{1}{c} \mathbf{E}^T \\
  \dfrac{1}{c} \mathbf{E}^T & \times \mathbf{B}^T
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
  0 & -\dfrac{1}{c} \mathbf{E}^T \\
  \dfrac{1}{c} \mathbf{E}^T & \mathbf{B} \times
\end{pmatrix}$$

$$F_{\mu \nu}=\partial_\mu A_\nu-\partial_\nu A_\mu=
\begin{pmatrix}
  0 & \dfrac{1}{c} \mathbf{E}^T \\
  -\dfrac{1}{c} \mathbf{E}^T & \times \mathbf{B}^T
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
  0 & \dfrac{1}{c} \mathbf{E}^T \\
  -\dfrac{1}{c} \mathbf{E}^T & \mathbf{B} \times
\end{pmatrix}$$

$$G^{\mu \nu}=\frac{\epsilon_{\mu \nu \alpha \beta}}{2}F_{\alpha \beta}=
\begin{pmatrix}
  0 & -\mathbf{B}^T \\
  \mathbf{B}^T & \times \left( -\dfrac{\mathbf{E}}{c} \right)^T
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
  0 & -\mathbf{B}^T \\
  \mathbf{B}^T & \left( -\dfrac{\mathbf{E}}{c} \right) \times
\end{pmatrix}$$

$$G_{\mu \nu}=\frac{\epsilon^{\mu \nu \alpha \beta}}{2}F^{\alpha \beta}=
\begin{pmatrix}
  0 & \mathbf{B}^T \\
  -\mathbf{B}^T & \times \left( -\dfrac{\mathbf{E}}{c} \right)^T
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
  0 & \mathbf{B}^T \\
  -\mathbf{B}^T & \left( -\dfrac{\mathbf{E}}{c} \right) \times
\end{pmatrix}$$

- Maxwell's equations

$$\square^2 A^{\mu}=\partial_\lambda F^{\lambda \mu}=\mu_0 J^{\mu} $$

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
  \dfrac{1}{c} \partial_t & \nabla^T
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
  0 & -\dfrac{1}{c} \mathbf{E}^T \\
  \dfrac{1}{c} \mathbf{E}^T & \times \mathbf{B}^T
\end{pmatrix}=\mu_0
\begin{pmatrix}
  \rho c & \mathbf{J}^T
\end{pmatrix}$$

$$\partial_\mu G^{\mu \nu}=0 $$

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
  \dfrac{1}{c} \partial_t & \nabla^T
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
  0 & -\mathbf{B}^T \\
  \mathbf{B}^T & \times \left( -\dfrac{\mathbf{E}}{c} \right)^T
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
  0 & \mathbf{0}^T
\end{pmatrix}$$

- Lorentz transformation

$$x'^\mu={\Lambda^\mu}_\nu \, x^\nu$$

$$x'_\mu={\Lambda_\mu}^\nu \, x_\nu$$

$$\partial'^\mu={\Lambda^\mu}_\nu \, \partial^\nu$$

$$\partial'_\mu={\Lambda_\mu}^\nu \, \partial_\nu$$

$$F'^{\mu \nu}={\Lambda_\mu}^\alpha {\Lambda_\nu}^\beta F^{\alpha \beta}$$

$$F'_{\mu \nu}={\Lambda^\mu}_\alpha {\Lambda^\nu}_\beta F_{\alpha \beta}$$

$$G'^{\mu \nu}={\Lambda_\mu}^\alpha {\Lambda_\nu}^\beta G^{\alpha \beta}$$

$$G'_{\mu \nu}={\Lambda^\mu}_\alpha {\Lambda^\nu}_\beta G_{\alpha \beta}$$

- Invariants and other relations

$$x^\mu x_\mu=x_\mu x^\mu=c^2 t^2-r^2=s^2$$

$$ds^2=
g_{\mu \nu} dx^\mu dx^\nu=
g^{\mu \nu} dx_\mu dx_\nu=
dx^\mu dx_\mu=
dx_\mu dx^\mu$$

$$u^\mu x_\mu=\gamma_u(c^2 t-\mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{r})$$

$$u^\mu u_\mu=c^2$$

$$a^\mu u_\mu=0$$

$$a^\mu a_\mu+b^\mu u_\mu=0$$

$$p^\mu p_\mu=m_0 c^2$$

$$F^\mu p_\mu=0$$

$$F^\mu F_\mu=-\gamma_u^2
\left[
  F^2-\frac{(\mathbf{F} \cdot \mathbf{u})^2}{c^2}
\right]$$

$$F^\mu x_\mu=\gamma_u \mathbf{F} \cdot (\mathbf{u} t-\mathbf{r})$$

$$F^\mu=\frac{dp^\mu}{d\tau}=m_0 a^\mu$$

$$k^\mu k_\mu=\frac{\omega^2}{c^2}-k^2$$

$$k^\mu x_\mu=\omega t-\mathbf{k} \cdot \mathbf{r}$$

$$J^\mu J_\mu=\rho^2 c^2-J^2$$

$$\partial_\mu J^\mu=0$$

$$\partial_\mu A^\mu=0$$

$$A^\mu A_\mu=\frac{\phi^2}{c^2}-A^2$$

$$J^\mu A_\mu=\rho \phi-\mathbf{J} \cdot \mathbf{A}$$

$$J^\mu K_\mu=0$$

$$K^\mu=F^{\mu \nu} J_\nu$$

$$F^\mu=qF^{\mu \nu} u_\nu$$

$$F^{\mu \nu} F_{\mu \nu}=2
\left(
  B^2-\frac{E^2}{c^2}
\right)$$

$$F^{\mu \nu} G_{\mu \nu}=-\frac{4\mathbf{E} \cdot \mathbf{B}}{c}$$

- Radiation reaction

$$m_0 a^\mu-qF^{\mu \nu} u_\nu=\frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0}
\frac{2q^2}{3c^3}
\left(
  b^\mu+\frac{a^\lambda a_\lambda}{c^2} u^\mu
\right)$$

- Every four-vectors can be transformed using Lorentz matrix.
- For easy clarification, we may use $E_{\mu \nu}$, $B_{\mu \nu}$ instead of $F_{\mu \nu}$, $G_{\mu \nu}$ and may extend the ideas to $D_{\mu \nu}$, $H_{\mu \nu}$, $P_{\mu \nu}$ and $M_{\mu \nu}$.
- Besides four-vectors, we can use quaternions instead, that is

$$ct+x i+y j+z k \in \mathbb{H}$$

Comment: your conventions related to the matrix forms for vector and covectors are misleading because are indistinguishable

Comment: @janmarqz The spatial parts are different.  Matrix operations work well for four-vector and E and B fields.  I will double check later.